How to avoid gdb to automatically show info on stop?
When I stop gdb I automatically get info. For example, consider the following, where I continue the execution of a program and then I stop it:
(gdb) c
Continuing.
^C
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x08002a2a in prvCheckTasksWaitingTermination () at Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/tasks.c:3650
3650                    while( uxDeletedTasksWaitingCleanUp > ( UBaseType_t ) 0U )
2: blink_led_state = 0 '\000'
(gdb)

when I stop the execution, I want to suppress all the following part:
^C
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x08002a2a in prvCheckTasksWaitingTermination () at Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/tasks.c:3650
3650                    while( uxDeletedTasksWaitingCleanUp > ( UBaseType_t ) 0U )
2: blink_led_state = 0 '\000'

i.e. I wish to visualize the following:
(gdb) c
Continuing.
(gdb)

or, at most the following
(gdb) c
Continuing.
^C
(gdb)


I don't think this is possible.

"I wish ...." -- why do you wish that? If that was possible, it would likely leave you very confused later on, when the program stops for some other reason.

@EmployedRussian for the same reason Gauss was studying complex numbers in the ‘700.
